# For loop in Java...creating pyramid

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a nested for loop that prints the following output:

```
                   1
                1  2  1
             1  2  4  2  1
          1  2  4  8  4  2  1
       1  2  4  8 16  8  4  2  1
    1  2  4  8 16 32 16  8  4  2  1
 1  2  4  8 16 32 64 32 16  8  4  2  1
```

I'm supposed to use two methods.

The main method is only supposed to get the number of rows desired from the user. 
I'm supposed to write another method called printPyramid that:

1. Has the number of rows
2. Prints a pyramid with that number of rows
3. Returns nothing.

So far, I have:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Pyramid {


    //Getting number of rows, calling printPyramid in main method

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get user input = number of lines to print in a pyramid
    System.out.println("Enter the number of lines to produce: ");
    int numLines = input.nextInt();

    //call method:
    printPyramid();

    }//End of main method

    //Making a new method...

    public static void printPyramid (int numLines) {

    int row;
    int col;

    row = 0;
    col = 0;

        for (row = 1; row <= numLines; row++){
            //print out n-row # of spaces
            for (col = 1; col <= numLines-row; col++){
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            //print out digits = 2*row-1 # of digits printed
            for (int dig= 1; dig <= 2*row-1; dig++){
                System.out.print(row + "  "); 
            }

        System.out.println();
        }//end of main for loop

    }//end of printPyramid

    }//end of class
```

I get errors and I can't figure out how to get it to print out correctly. 
I believe the methods are messed up?

Comment: can you post your errors? quite hard to fix an error if you know nothing about it. **and** is this homework?

Comment: *I get errors...* What errors are you having?

Comment: please break down your question to be specific, showing a single function/compartment that is broken with any related code and debug errors

Comment: adding homework tag...feel free to remove it if this is incorrect.

Comment: @dbyrne That tag is deprecated.

Comment: @dbyrne [Homework is dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: You forgot to define the class name and imports have to be defined first. You are on the right way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two big errors here. Firstly, **ALL** with Java are classes so you have to put that *main* method inside a class. For example:

```
public class Anything {
    public static void main ...

    public static void printPyramid ...
}
```

Second one, you have to call the method `printPyramid` inside the main, because it will not be executed if isn't called first.

```
public class Anything {
    public static void main ... {
         ...
         printPyramid (numLines);
         ...
    }

    public static void printPyramid ...
}
```

I hope this small indications help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it down to only 1 error...

        `Pyramid.java:28: error: method printPyramid in class Pyramid cannot be applied to given types;`

        `printPyramid();`
        `required: int`
        `found: no arguments`
        `reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length`

Comment: @user1368970 It was just a example, you have to call `printPyramid` with an int as a parameter. The error explain it to you: `required: int found: no arguments`